# How to change Geo information to real name

Tags: api, geo

Is there a way to convert Geo information to real place name? For example, I take a photo on "137-159 New Montgomery St San Francisco, CA 94105", the Geotagging information is :
geo:37.786971,-122.399677
when I type the geo in google map, it can show the place name to me. Does google provide API to get it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Google Maps API GeoCoder GClientGeocoder.getLocations()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#ReverseGeocoding) provides reverse geocoding as well:

> The term geocoding generally refers to translating a human-readable address into a point on the map. The process of doing the converse, translating a point into a human-readable address, is known as reverse geocoding. 
>   The GClientGeocoder.getLocations() method supports both standard and reverse geocoding. If you pass this method a GLatLng object instead of a String address, the geocoder will perform a reverse lookup and return a structured JSON object of the closest addressable location. Note that the closest addressable location may be some distance from the original latitude and longitude values of the query, if the supplied GLatLng is not an exact match for any addressable locations.